# Convert List<T> to Dictionary with strategy

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

I have List < DTO >  where DTO class looks like this,

```
 private class DTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

I create objects and add it to List.

```
var dto1 = new DTO { Name = "test", Count = 2 };
var dto2 = new DTO { Name = "test", Count = 3 };
var dtoCollection = new List<DTO> {dto1, dto2};
```

Now my requirement is I need to create an Dictionary from the dtoCollection whose Key is **Name** field and value is Sum of **Count** fields.

For example, if you convert the above dtoCollection to Dictionary, the entry should be like

> Key = "test" , Value = "5"

Where Value is obtained from summing up the **Count** fields whose **Name** fields are same

Answer (score 12):

I guess this will do what you need:

```
dtoCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => y.Count))
```

Comment: My thought exactly. And don't forget to include `System.Linq`!

Answer (score 1):

Following is the linq query

```
var dict = dtoCollection.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Select(y=>y.Count).Sum());
```