# Group a List based on uniqueness

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

This question is a slightly modified version of [Convert List<T> to Dictionary with strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377885/convert-listt-to-dictionary-with-strategy/13378005#13378005)

I have List < DTO > where DTO class looks like this,

```
private class DTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

I create objects and add it to List.

```
var dto1 = new DTO { Name = "test", Count = 2 };
var dto2 = new DTO { Name = "test", Count = 3 };
var dtoCollection = new List<DTO> {dto1, dto2};
```

Now my requirement is I need to create a List from the dtoCollection where Name field should be unique across the entire List.

For example, if you convert the above dtoCollection to the required List from, the resultant list should be like:

List < DTO >  count should be 1;

The object inside the list should be a single DTO with **Name** as "test" and **Count** as 5

Where Count is obtained from summing up the Count fields in all DTO's whose Name fields are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newList = dtoCollection.GroupBy(d => d.Name)
             .Select(g => new DTO(){ Name=g.Key, Count=g.Select(d => d.Count).Sum()})
             .ToList();
```

Comment: What if my DTO had an extra field called Surname? Consider the surname is unique for a given name. How do I modify the above query.

Comment: @Rockstart `GroupBy(d => new {d.Name,d.SurName})`

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
var result = dtoCollection.GroupBy(dto => dto.Name)
                          .Select(group => new DTO 
                                           {
                                               Name = group.Key,
                                               Count = group.Sum(dto => dto.Count) 
                                           })
                          .ToList();
```

This works by grouping the DTOs by name, and then from each group extracting a new DTO named from the group's key and count set to the sum of its members' counts.

Comment: What if my DTO had an extra field called Surname? Consider the surname is unique for a given name. How do I modify the above query.

Comment: The clean way would be extract that out into the key as well `GroupBy(dto => new { dto.Name, dto.Surname })` and then extract both components of the key out from the group. But since you are confident that the surname is unique for a name, you could also just extract out the surname of the first member of the group with my original code: `[...] , Surname = group.First().Surname, [...]`.